# C - Segmentation fault (core dumped) error when running my program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50, caesar-cipher

In order to practice in c, in my *caesar.c* program I'm using my encrypt_text method in order to encrypt a given text (for which user is prompted). I’m using the Caesar cipher function and as a key, I’m using the *argv[1]* element (casted in int).

In the first if statement I check that, running the program, the user types only one element (after the program name), that the element is not a zero and that is composed by only digits (trough the helper method *checkString*). If the conditions are respected, the user is prompted for the text to encrypt. Otherwise the user is asked to run the program again with the message: *Usage:./caesar Key* .

So, everything seems to work correctly but, when I run the program typing only the name of the program (so, basically, filling argv[] array with only one element), I encounter a *segmentation fault (core dumped)* error.

So, if I run the program with the command *./caesar 3* everything works correctly but if I run the program with the command *./caesar*  (without a number after it), then the segmentation fault error happens.

Basically, also in this last case, I need the same *Usage:./caesar Key* message to be returned.

I read a lot about this kind of problem that is related to trying to access memory that is not allowed but, at the moment, I did not find the reason why is happening in my specific program.

Some suggestion?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void encrypt_text (string text, const int tlen, int shift, char* cipher);//encrypt method
int checkString(string strToCheck);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int key = atoi(argv[1]);//cast argv[1] to an integer

    if ((argc == 2) && (key != 0) && checkString(argv[1]) == 1)
    {

        //include cypher method
        string text = get_string("Text to cypher: ");
        int tlen = strlen(text);
        char cipher[tlen +1]; cipher[tlen] ='\0';
        int shift = key; // key

        //printf ("Text :\t\t%s\n", text);
        encrypt_text (text, tlen, shift, cipher);
        printf ("ciphertext:%s\n", cipher);
        text[0] = '\0';
        return 0;

    } else {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar Key \n");
         return 1;
    }
}


//encrypting method
void encrypt_text (string text, const int tlen, int shift, char* cipher) {
    char lower[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char upper[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    shift %= 26; // more than 26 make cycle[s]
    for (int ti=0; ti < tlen; ++ti) {
        if (islower (text[ti]))
            cipher[ti] = lower[(text[ti] - 'a' + shift) % 26];
        else if (isupper (text[ti]))
            cipher[ti] = upper[(text[ti] - 'A' + shift) % 26];
        else
            cipher[ti] = text[ti];
    }
}


//helper method for checking only digits strings
int checkString(string strToCheck) {

      for (int i = 0, n = strlen(strToCheck); i < n; i++) {
          int test = isdigit(strToCheck[i]);

          if (test == 0) {
              return 0;//found a non digit
              break;
          }
      }
return 1;//string has only digit
}
```

Comment: `string` type doesn't exist in C.

Comment: @imperosol It's a `cs50.h` thing, I believe. And it's really just typedef for `char *`, IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

When your program is executed with no arguments, `argv[1]` won't have any information about the arguments. `NULL` is put there in some environments.

Therefore, you mustn't execute `atoi(argv[1])` in this case.

Check should be added to the statement

```c
int key = atoi(argv[1]);
```

like

```c
int key = 0;
if (argv >= 2) {
    key = atoi(argv[1]);
}
```

or (if using ternary operator is allowed):

```c
int key = argv >= 2 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 0;
```

Comment: hanks for your support. I just mooved int key inside the if statment but the problem persist.

Comment: @gianni85 I rewrote my answer because I found that `key` is used in the condition.